# How do I correctly set the PWM registers so I can control the brightness of the LED? C/Arduino UNO

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

```
const int photo_resistor PROGMEM = 0;
const int red_pin PROGMEM = 6; 

void setup(){
    TCCR0A = 0;
    TCCR0B = 0;
  
    // output for traffic light led
    SET_BIT(DDRD, red_pin);
    
    //photo resistor
    CLEAR_BIT(DDRC, photo_resistor);
    
    //adc topic 10
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA, ADEN);
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA, ADPS2);
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA, ADPS1);
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA, ADPS0);
    SET_BIT(ADMUX, REFS0);
    
    //pwm with timer 0 Red & Yellow Led
    //prescale
    CLEAR_BIT(TCCR0B, CS01);
    SET_BIT(TCCR0B, CS02);
    SET_BIT(TCCR0B, CS00);
    //Compare for red
    CLEAR_BIT(TCCR0A, COM0A0);
    SET_BIT(TCCR0A, COM0A1);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    //WGM-Fast PWM
    SET_BIT(TCCR0A, WGM00);
    SET_BIT(TCCR0A, WGM01);
    CLEAR_BIT(TCCR0B, WGM02);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
void process(){ 
    //sensor
    char sensor_buffer[64];
    SET_BIT(ADCSRA, ADSC);
    while(ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC) ) {}
    uint16_t sensor_data = ADC;
    itoa(sensor_data, (char *)sensor_buffer,10);
    Serial.println(sensor_data);
    //always on green
    OCR0A = sensor_data/4;


}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(){
    setup();
    for (;;){
        process();
    }
}
```

My code's logic is working but, not sure what I'm missing. The photoresistor is working and providing me a value from 969 to 49. Here I'm using ADC to convert the data so I can control the LED's brightness with PWM. What am I doing wrong? Here is an image of the arduino in tinkercad.

[image]

Comment: I don't see where you'er updating the brightness. Wouldn't you need to do something like here - https://www.deviceplus.com/arduino/the-basics-of-arduino-adjusting-led-brightness/ and do like `analog_write(red_pin, <something 0 - 255>)`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this should help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVm0qVJ56II, you might need `analog_write(red_pin, <something 0 - 255>)`